# Undefined behaviour

Tags: java, c++, undefined-behavior

I'm making some simulations on C++ and I've faced a weird problem. I have the following function which returns a vector of double:

```
vector<double> processSimulation(int Q){
//do things
vector<double> output;
output.push_back(mean);
output.push_back(variance);
return output;
}
```

In the main, I have the following:

```
//define Q
vector<double>::iterator it = processSimulation(Q).begin();
double mean = *it;
double variance = *(it+1);
```

The problem is that I get a wrong number for the mean (something with e-305) and a correct number for the variance.
I tried to explained this behaviour myself and I think that this was probably caused by and **undefined behaviour**, since the iterator points to the old vector in the function, which is now out of scope and exists no more. Am I correct?
*Probably I was just lucky with variance being correct, as it could've also been wrong.*

I changed the code to

```
vector<double> output = processSimulation(Q);
vector<double>::iterator it = output.begin();
//same as before
```

and it works just fine, so this strengthens my hypotesis.

Also I noticed a *debugger weirdness*: when trying to figure out what was happening (before fixing the code), I looked at the values of mean and variance through debugging and they were BOTH wrong. Though, when I runned the program only the mean was wrong (I've tried this many times and it was always: both wrong while debugging, mean wrong and variance correct while running). **What's happening in here?**

*Java question*: well, this problem I've met is really bugging me, because often in Java, to shorten things, I didn't define new objects but used methods directly on the function that would return that object (like in this example). Though, I've never faced any problem. Have I always been doing things *inadvertently* (and luckily)? Or is just that **in Java no such behaviour exists**, since functions that should return objects, in truth, return pointers to them and the true objects are always in the heap (and are garbaged when there's no reference to them)?

Hope you can clarify my doubts!

Comment: Please add the `// do things` code. I would guess that you aren't initializing something correctly.

Comment: Why are you returning a `vector<double>` anyway, rather than using output parameters for the mean and variance?

Comment: @AndyTurner That would not be better C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Returning a container which can have any number of elements seems like a much worse option than saying "here are exactly 2 output arguments". Or do you mean it would be better to define a 2-element struct and return an instance of that?

Comment: @AndyTurner There are easier, more concise ways to get around that problem, see my answer. The main advantage I see there is preserving the `output = f(input)` style so one does not need to worry about side effects on the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very common mistake people make when they get lazy about chaining calls on *rvalues* instead of storing the result in a local variable.

```
vector<double>::iterator it = processSimulation(Q).begin();
```

In the above, your `processSimulation(Q)` call returns `vector<double>`.  You then obtain an iterator to the beginning of the vector and store that.  Now that the resulting vector is no longer in scope, it is destroyed.  That leaves a dangling iterator.

And now you start using it.  Remember, that iterator contains valid information, but it's pointing into an object that no longer exists:

```
double mean = *it;            // undefined behaviour
double variance = *(it+1);    // undefined behaviour
```

Think of it as being a little bit like this:

```
vector<double>::iterator it;
{
    vector<double> result = processSimulation(Q);
    it = result.begin();
}
double mean = *it;    // boom
```

When you change the code to store the return value in a local variable, the behaviour will be defined, provided the vector stays in scope for the entire time you are using the iterator.

And so this is correct (excepting the C++ style-related comments on your question):

```
vector<double> output = processSimulation(Q);
vector<double>::iterator it = output.begin();
double mean = *it;
double variance = *(it+1);
```

But you could just have easily ditched the iterator and used the array index operator:

```
double mean = output[0];
double variance = output[1];
```

You might want to consider returning your own struct that encapsulates this information, rather than a vector.  Or at the very least switch to using `std::pair<double, double>`.

Comment: Thank you! This was as I guessed then. Also, thank you, for the suggestion about using a struct or a pair. I have a question about this: you'd rather use a struct or pair because it seems _redundant_ to use a vector for a fixed size object? Or are there more advantages to this approach?

Comment: The bigger picture here is what that return type actually _says_ about your code.  It does not say "I am going to return a mean and variance, where the mean comes first, and there will always be exactly two values".  It actually says "I'll return an arbitrary number of values, or possibly none at all".  If you get into the habit of making code that expresses its intent clearly, you will find yourself making fewer mistakes in the long run.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips :)

Comment: And it is correct that it "is just that in Java no such behaviour exists, since functions that should return objects, in truth, return pointers to them and the true objects are always in the heap (and are garbaged when there's no reference to them)?" (your words quoted)